# Search for texts recursively under a td node in an html table

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, lxml

I am crawling an html table with Python. So far I've successfully parsed out the table with:

```
root = etree.fromstring(browser.page_source, etree.HTMLParser())
rows = root.xpath("//table[@class='ms-listviewtable']/tbody/tr")
```

Now I'd like to parse the columns one by one in each row with a `for` loop like:

```
for row in rows:
    cols = row.xpath("./td")
    texts = [col.xpath("./findtextforme()") for col in cols)]
    # findtextforme() is a imaginary functionality
```

Why can't I simply do `col.xpath("./text()")` or `col.findtext("./")`? Because the places they put the texts are inconsistent across or even within columns of that table, including`td/text()`, `td/div/a/text()`, `td/div/font/text()`, `td/div/div/text()`... etc.

Hence I want something which can recursively look for texts under a given td node. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use [`.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) which aggregates a "text" of an HTML element:

> Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of its children, with no markup.

```
texts = [col.text_content() for col in cols]
```

Comment: It gives me `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'text_content'`

Comment: @ytu right, you need to use `lxml.html.fromstring()` instead of `etree.fromstring()`. Don't forget to `import lxml.html`.

Comment: I did `from lxml import html` and then `html.fromstring(browser.page_source, etree.HTMLParser())`, but get `TypeError: Argument must be string or unicode`.

Comment: @ytu just to check, you've omitted that `etree.HTMLParser()` argument, right?

Comment: Oh! `html.fromstring(browser.page_source, etree.HTMLParser())` gives me `TypeError` but `html.fromstring(browser.page_source)` doesn't. How mysterious. Would you please enlighten me the difference between `html.fromstring` and `etree.fromstring`?

Comment: @ytu it's simple, using `lxml.html` [basically enables the special HTML parsing API](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html).

Comment: I see. So is it correct to say that usually using `lxml.html` is better than using `lxml.etree` when parsing HTML pages?